# How to transfer secret.json to Azure?

Tags: azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have seen tons of article on how to manage secrets in .net core app, but none which show how to tansfer those to Azure appsetting when deploying to Azure.

I have manually created setting in azure portal, but my app still fails.

Comment: You can consult this document, which may be helpful to you. I will follow the documentation for further attempts, and hope it helps you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows